# append text to p:editor from backing bean

Tags: primefaces

[Related example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241869/insert-image-into-primefaces-editor)

```
String value = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
             .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("editor_input");
```

This code work getting and updating p:inputTextarea or p:outputLabel values but I can't make to work this code with p:editor - throwing exception:

```
com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError org.primefaces.expression.ComponentNotFoundException: Cannot find component for expression "form:editor_input" referenced from "j_id1"
```

"form:editor_input" is an id of p:editor from my page source. 
Is it possible to append text from backing bean to this PF component?

Comment: Why can't you just update the String the editor binds into on the bean ("value"-attribute)?

Comment: Sorry I'm not very strong in programming, but in the bean editor value is null while it is not submited right? Example: user opens page with editor, type some text and uploads some image and at this moment I can't append picture link to existing text from bean. It's why I'm trying to update editor value from uploadListener method in backing bean updating requestcontext

Comment: You're right, the editor needs to be submitted. But you can probably do that with ajax. For example, if you use p:fileUpload (with ajax) you can try to specify "@form" in both process and update attribute, and in the fileUploadListener add the String to the editor. I haven't tried it though... If that does'nt work you could maybe use a remoteCommand like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994966/pass-value-of-another-input-component-when-uploading-file-via-pfileupload-mode

Comment: @form attribute did'nt helped in update and process... But I solved my problem changing to basic upload component : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml which has submit button.  This question I leave open because it was about problem to change editor value from requestmap